# How to open CMD from a flutter desktop application

Tags: flutter, dart, cmd, exec

I have this app idea, but it depends heavily on CMD, so I want to know if I can open any other app (eg. CMD) from within a flutter desktop app.

I know in java it could be done using exec(), but is there any equivalence for it in dart/flutter ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, take a look at the [Process class in dart:io](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-io/Process-class.html) which provides a few ways to spawn processes from a Dart program.

Comment: so basically this will allow me to execute commands without even opening the CMD right ?

Comment: Yes. Also note that if you are using Mac you will need to disable sandbox mode or you will get a permission denied exception. Comment out `<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key><true/>` in `macos/Runner/*.entitlements`.

Comment: can I see what's process is doing for example if you run specific task in cmd it gives o/p or progress and if so how can i get it?